# Alien Dictionary Algorithm - Time Complexity

Tags: javascript, time, time-complexity

I implemented the Alien Dictionary algorithm, but I'm not sure about its time complexity.

Problem:
In an alien language, surprisingly they also use english lowercase letters, but possibly in a different order. The order of the alphabet is some permutation of lowercase letters.

Given a sequence of words written in the alien language, and the order of the alphabet, return true if and only if the given words are sorted lexicographicaly in this alien language.

Algorithm:

```
var isAlienSorted = function(words, order) {
     if(!words || words.length === 0)   return true;
    
    const dict = {};
    for (let i=0; i<order.length; i++) {
        dict[order[i]] = i;
    }
    
    for(let i=1; i<words.length; i++) {
        if(!helper(words[i-1], words[i], dict)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
};

const helper = (str1, str2, order) => {
    for(let j=0; j<str1.length; j++) {
        if(j > str2.length-1)   return false;
        if(order[str1[j]] > order[str2[j]])
            return false
        else if(order[str1[j]] < order[str2[j]])
            return true;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

I believe the time complexity is O(N) where N is the number of elements in the words array, but I'm not sure because I have another loop inside the helper function. Does it make the time complexity O(N2)?

thanks

Comment: I think you are correct.  For each word, you are looping through it a second time.  So I think O(N^2) sounds correct.

Comment: do you have some examples as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
isAlienSorted = function(words, order) {
     if(!words || words.length === 0)   return true;
    
    const dict = {};
    for (let i=0; i<order.length; i++) { --------------------O(N) (one loop only)
        dict[order[i]] = i;
    }
    
    for(let i=1; i<words.length; i++) { ----------------------O(N) (one loop only)
        if(!helper(words[i-1], words[i], dict)){-------------O(N) (one loop only)
            return false;
        } --------------------------------O(N*N) 
    }
    
    return true;
};



const helper = (str1, str2, order) => {
    for(let j=0; j<str1.length; j++) { ----------------------O(N) (one loop only)
        if(j > str2.length-1)   return false;
        if(order[str1[j]] > order[str2[j]])
            return false
        else if(order[str1[j]] < order[str2[j]])
            return true;
    }
    
    return true;
}

TimeComplexity : O(N*N)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. Is it possible to make it O(N)?

Comment: I can try, kindly provide the some input and cases to check

Comment: Sure. Input: words = ["word","world","row"], order = "worldabcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz"
Output: false
Explanation: As 'd' comes after 'l' in this language, then words[0] > words[1], hence the sequence is unsorted.

Comment: I have tried here and it is working. Need to put edge cases but I guess it is possible to make it in O(N). You may also check and let me know if you need more information on the same.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nzb9q2

Comment: Thank you for effort, but it failed for the input: words = ["hello","last"]
order = "hlabcdefgijkmnopqrstuvwxyz". It should return true